# Default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: android, java-8

Why do we get this error in Android Studio 3.0 RC1?

```
 com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: 
default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24
```

According to the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features), the feature "Default and static interface methods" is compatible with **Any** min-sdk version.

I tracked this down to a java-library that calls [Comparator.naturalOrder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()) - which has been added in API level 24.
So I would not expect any error-message at all for this code in a java-library.

When I use the code in my own android-app or lib java code, I see the correct lint message: "Call requires API level 24)"

Is the error-message wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: "Call requires API level 24" messages appear for source code, not libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right - I have clarified the question

Comment: Perhaps the implementation of `naturalOrder()` happens to use the Java 8 features you're getting the error about. That's just a guess. You said that you tried using it in your own code -- if you skip over the Lint error and do a build, do you get the same error message that your library is giving you?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, `naturalOrder) is a static interface method. But I should not get an error, because the android build tools [claim](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features) to be able to handle static interface methods for any min-sdk.  
When I ignore the lint-message and compile my own code, I get the same error-message.

Comment: "But I should not get an error, because the android build tools claim to be able to handle static interface methods for any min-sdk" -- my guess is that it is a documentation error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just found out that it works as expected when I activate the [D8 dexer](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html) which is planned to be the default for Android Studio 3.1

In the project `gradle.properties`, add:

```
android.enableD8=true
```

Now the code compiles as expected and I still get the expected linter messages.

Comment: Although be careful. According to Google Dev Blog: "There is currently a known issue around 64-bit devices running Lollipop. Give D8 a try but please don't use it to deploy your app to Google Play. We would love to hear your feedback. You can file a bug report using this link."

Comment: that [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64740479) is already fixed

Comment: Does anyone know why changing the dexer fixes the original issue? If the problem was really that a dependency was requiring API >= 24 what does the dexer have to do with it?

Comment: 1) The original problem was, that the compilation failed with an error-message because a library contained a static interface method: this is strange, because (according to the Android docs) static interface methods should just work: so using the new Dexer fixes this issue.  

2) The other thing is that the function `naturalOrder()` was added in API version 24: So if you compile for a lower API, you should get a Linter message, but no compile error (which works in both Dexer settings)

Comment: This fixes the original problem, then I get r8.errors.CompilationError: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file.

Answer (score 4):

If the java-library that you're talking about was guava, you can try to upgrade it to the latest android-specific build

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'
```

This fixed for me

Answer (score 0):

From guava v24 we have two alternative versions: Android or JRE. So, in this case you need to include the dependency as:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-android'
```

Find all the details within the repo: https://github.com/google/guava

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs due to Guava, then the solution, as per the official documentation from Google is:
https://github.com/google/guava

Change the dependency to (version is current as of this writing):

```
api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'
```

This fixed the issue for me.