# Android kotlin extension error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-extension

> java.lang.VerifyError: .../utils/KotlinViewExtKt$animateFadeOut$1

Getting that error while running app on emulator **PRE Lolipop (<21 api)**

Function causing the trouble:

```
fun View.animateFadeOut(animDuration: Long = 250) {
    this.animate()
            .alpha(0F)
            .setDuration(animDuration)
            .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation, isReverse)
                    show(false)
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                    show(false)
                }

                override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {
                }
            })
            .start()
}

fun View.show(show: Boolean) {
    val vis = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    if (visibility != vis) {
        visibility = vis
    }
}
```

Pointing on `.setListener` line.

Works perfectly on 21+ api.

AS versio: 3.0.1. Kotlin version: 1.2.21 (tried 1.1.51).

What could be the reason? My bad or kotlin?
Multidex is enabled.

Comment: use [AnimatorListenerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html) instead of **AnimatorListener** without overriding  `onAnimationEnd(Animator animation, boolean isReverse)` and `onAnimationStart(Animator animation, boolean isReverse)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda/issues/42) and [this fix:](https://github.com/GiveNow/givenow-android/blob/40cfb77d148ba2590424a6d07aaf237f35d60a4c/app/src/main/java/io/givenow/app/interfaces/AnimatorEndListener.java)

**ViewExtension.kt**

```
fun View.animateFadeOut(animDuration: Long = 250L) {
    this.animate()
            .alpha(0F)
            .setDuration(animDuration)
            .setListener(object : AbstractAnimatorListener() {

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation, isReverse)
                    show(false)
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                    show(false)
                }
            })
            .start()
}

fun View.show(show: Boolean) {
    val vis = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    if (visibility != vis) {
        visibility = vis
    }
}
```

**AbstractAnimatorListener.kt**

```
abstract class AbstractAnimatorListener : Animator.AnimatorListener {

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {}

    override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {}

    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) {
        onAnimationEnd(animation)
    }

    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) {
        onAnimationStart(animation)
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation**

Try to remove these methods added in API 26 using Java 8 Defaults and use alternative animation:

[Animator.AnimatorListener:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html)

> **onAnimationEnd added in API level 26**
>
> ```
> void onAnimationEnd (Animator animation, boolean isReverse)
> ```
>
> **onAnimationStart added in API level 26**
>
> ```
> void onAnimationStart (Animator animation, boolean isReverse)
> ```

These methods can be overridden, though not required, to get the additional play direction info when an animation starts.

[AnimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html):

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API 26) the AnimatorSet API supports
>   seeking and playing in reverse.

---

**Note:**

```
/**
 * Skipping calling super when overriding this method results in
 * {@link #onAnimationStart(Animator)} not getting called.
 */
default void onAnimationStart(Animator animation, boolean isReverse) {
    onAnimationStart(animation);
}
```

I need to add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44297713/1009132) to my `build.gradle` file to test it

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

or replace

```
super.onAnimationEnd(animation, isReverse)
```

by

```
onAnimationEnd(animation)
```

to avoid the error:

> Super calls to Java default methods are prohibited in JVM target 1.6.
>   Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8'

And add the next line to my gradle.properties file [thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46754337/1009132)

```
android.enableD8=true
```

to avoid the exception:

> com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: default or static interface
>   method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24

It compiles now, launching a kitKat emulator just now...

It works, and MultiDex is also enabled in my project.

Sorry, I cannot reproduce it.

Alternatively, remove the two methods using Java 8 defaults, it also works.

---

**Note2:**

Arpan suggestion about AnimatorListenerAdapter would work but it's not necessary.

You can remove those methods, change the animation and create:

```
object EmptyAnimatorListener : Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationCancel(p0: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animator?) {}
}
```

And use delegation like this:

```
    .setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener by EmptyAnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
            // Do something
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            // Do something
        }
    })
```

---

**Note3:**

Reproduced adding it to an extension function:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: ...android, PID: 3409
>                     java.lang.VerifyError: com/.../ui/common/extension/android/view/ViewExtensionKt$animateFadeOut$1

- Removing the Api 26 methods using Java Defaults solves the issue.
- Replacing the super call calling your onAnimationEnd also solves it:

  ```
      override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) {
          onAnimationEnd(animation)
      }
  ```
- Calling super.onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?, isReverse: Boolean) requires API 26:

[image]

- Decompiling Kotlin Bytecode shows these methods cannot be resolved:

[image]