# How to fix Error:WARNING in butterknife.Unbinder.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Recently we noticed these warnings in AS 3.0.1:

```
Error:WARNING in butterknife.Unbinder.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: butterknife.Unbinder.<clinit>:()V

Error:WARNING in android.support.v4.widget.AutoSizeableTextView.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: android.support.v4.widget.AutoSizeableTextView.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationCallback.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationCallback.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$ConnectionFactory.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$ConnectionFactory.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.bumptech.glide.load.Key.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.bumptech.glide.load.Key.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.bumptech.glide.load.model.Headers.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.bumptech.glide.load.model.Headers.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.squareup.picasso.Cache.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.squareup.picasso.Cache.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$RequestTransformer.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$RequestTransformer.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.squareup.okhttp.Dns.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.squareup.okhttp.Dns.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.squareup.okhttp.internal.framed.PushObserver.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.framed.PushObserver.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.FileSystem.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.FileSystem.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.layer.lsdka.lsdka.a.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.layer.lsdka.lsdka.a.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.layer.lsdka.lsdka.c.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.layer.lsdka.lsdka.c.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.lsdka.lsdka.lsdka.e.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.lsdka.lsdka.lsdka.e.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.lsdka.lsdka.lsdka.lsdkb.i.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.lsdka.lsdka.lsdka.lsdkb.i.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in com.lsdka.lsdka.lsdka.lsdkb.o.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: com.lsdka.lsdka.lsdka.lsdkb.o.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in retrofit.ErrorHandler.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: retrofit.ErrorHandler.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in retrofit.RequestInterceptor.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: retrofit.RequestInterceptor.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in retrofit.RestAdapter$Log.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: retrofit.RestAdapter$Log.<clinit>:()V
Error:WARNING in kotlin.coroutines.experimental.ContinuationInterceptor.<clinit>:()V: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 16) for interface methods: kotlin.coroutines.experimental.ContinuationInterceptor.<clinit>:()V
```

The code compiles fine, but it's just annoying to see lots of red errors.
Someone knows how to get rid of them?

Comment: Use java 8 for compilation . set it in build.gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754337/default-or-static-interface-method-used-without-min-sdk-version-24

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I found that question but the symptoms (errors) are not the same @duggu

Answer (score 0):

As [ADM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168607/adm) suggested, it gets resolved if in build.gradle java 8 is set.

```
compileOptions.with {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

UPDATE:
The warning messages appeared again. Looks like I was confused and haven't seen those messages because of the buildCache.

Problem not solved.